# How to make RTSP server stream / send H264 format using Java

Tags: java, server, h.264, vlc, rtsp

I am currently trying to make an `RTSP server` which streams `H264` formatted videos using `Java`.

My `RTSP client` will be a computer monitor which is connected to server via ethernet cable. I have been told that the monitor is able to show incoming `H264` formatted videos. I do not have the monitor yet.

Even though I don't have the monitor yet, I wanted to see something working. I managed this by using a `vlc media player` instance as server and another `vlc media player` instance as client following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsahDWNByVQ). Now I must implement a `RTSP server` which can stream `H264` formats. I could not find any information about how to do this using Java. Does `VLC media player` have `Java API` for this, or is there any source which can walk me through how to achieve this with `Java`?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) I found a good starting point, if I can manage I'll put solution as source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

1. You need to prepare your environment following [this](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/installation). Make sure you use all with 64 bit or all with 32 bit versions of VLC, IDE, Java and OS.
2. You must create a class and add following code block to it:

code block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
     // your VLC installation path
     NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");

     String media = "your file url"; // example = file:///C:/test.mp4
     // you are gonna use below value on the client 
     String[] options = {":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://localhost:8554/stream"};

     System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'"); 

     MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(); 
     HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer(); 
     mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options, ":no-sout-rtp-sap", ":no-sout-standard-sap", ":sout-all", ":sout-keep");

     // Don't exit
     Thread.currentThread().join();
}
```

3. Now you can use VLC media player as RTSP client. Open VLC media
   player on the left corner click "Media", then click "Open Network
   Stream". Enter the network Url we had given above
   "rtsp://localhost:8554/stream" and let it wait. After you do step 4 press "play".
4. Run your class as Java application.

Now you should be able to see your video in the VLC media player which you opened as RTSP Client before.